# How to use to ffmpeg create video collage from a video captured by an app?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am working on a android app, which is based on video collage, in which I have to create collage from selected or captured video. There are different types of collage I have to implement. I have implemented most of them.

But I am stuck when I try to create a specific type of collage.

I have to create a collage in which all video should play one be one.

I have to combine 16 videos all together in a frame, and play them one by one.

It should be look like this:

[image]

For now all video are playing together. What should I do so that all videos play one by one?

Comment: pls post the cmd you have used to merge videos.

Comment: i am hitting array of commands for that i can give you a single command

Comment: "-i " + input1 + " -i " + input2
            + " -filter_complex [0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid] -map [vid]  -map 0 -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -crf 40  -preset veryfast "
            + output1;

Answer (score 0):

I think the "**concat**" part is missing from your command.

Update in your commented cmd.

```
"-i " + input1 + " -i " + input2 + " -filter_complex [0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid] [0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a] -map [vid] -map 0 -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -crf 40 -preset veryfast " + output1;
```

Haven't tried it but hope it works.

Comment: "-i " + input1 + " -i " + input2
            + " -filter_complex [0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a] -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -crf 23  -preset veryfast "
            + output;

Comment: are you using any library of ffmpeg? which one?

Comment: com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg:FFmpegAndroid

Comment: And, it should be inside the -filter_complex example `-filter complex “[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]” ` . pls make sure it is.

Comment: above i have mentioned my command for two videos,  can you please let know what i need to change

Comment: "-i " + input1 + " -i " + input2
            + " -filter_complex [0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid] -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -crf 23  -preset veryfast "
            + output;


 . This cmd is working fine but its merging two videos not concating
. I want to create padding and then concate them
.I have achieved   merging and concatenation  separately but not together   
. In android for concatenation we need to create .ts version of that video only then we can merge videos

Comment: pls add `[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0]` before the concat. Example `[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]` . I tells ffmpeg what streams to send to the concat filter